# MediatR not finding Handlers on IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core, mediatr

I am writing a simple application in .NET Core 3.0 with different layers and using MediatR to make my code clean.
I have 5 different layers: API, Application, Application.IO, Domain and Infrastructure with my IRequestHandler in Application and my IRequest in Application.IO and registering my handlers happens in the Startup class in the API layer.

When running this locally I have no issues but when I deployed this to an IIS server I keep getting the error:

> Error constructing handler for request of type
>   MediatR.IRequestHandler`2[WerfRegistratie.Application.IO.Queries.GetPersonQuery,WerfRegistratie.Application.IO.Queries.GetPersonQueryResponse].
>   Register your handlers with the container. See the samples in GitHub
>   for examples.

Comment: Show how you register handlers, i.e. your `ConfigureServices`. And describe how you publish the site.

Comment: At first I just used this             services.AddMediatR(typeof(CreatePersonCommandHandler).GetTypeInfo().Assembly); 
But I have since then tried multiple other ways (including adding startup). The publish just happens through downloading the publish profile from azure and manually deploying it

Comment: Add your code into the question: handler class, query, registration and how you call it.

Answer (score 0):

To register Mediatr you can use:

```
services.AddMediatR(typeof(Startup);
```

To register your handlers you can use:

```
services.AddMediatorHandlers(typeof(CreatePersonCommandHandler).GetTypeInfo().Assembly);
```

Both should be present in your startup.cs file in the ConfigureServices method

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services){
    services.AddMediatR(typeof(Startup);
 services.AddMediatorHandlers(typeof(CreatePersonCommandHandler).GetTypeInfo().Assembly);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of searching it seems the issues wasn't with the registration of the handlers (which were correct) but with dependency injection of a repository in my handler. After fixing this everything worked as expected

Comment: How did you fix the issue? Can u please mention some details?

Comment: Originally I had set up my startup so my handlers got registered first and then I added the dependency injection for my entityframework. Switching them around ended up being enough